# Does the "50 questions in 30 days" rate limit mean 30 calendar days, or 720 hours?

Tags: support, questions, rate-limiting

All I'm wondering, is if the 30 day timer that one has after submitting 50 questions lasts for 30 calender days, or exactly 720 hours from when the question was asked.

Comment: If you're that close to the limit that a few hours is going to make a difference...

Comment: Just curiosity man.

Comment: Well, I see 45 questions in 33 days, so it's not quite academical for you ;)

Comment: Haha simply curiosity, figured it was about the site's features so it wouldn't be a terrible idea to ask it on meta.

Comment: Sure, nothing wrong with asking here. If you don't get an authoritative answer, you're close enough to test, if you put in a bit of effort :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latter.

The check is performed *when you try to submit a post* - at that time, if you've posted at least 50 questions in the last 30 days, you'll be blocked. If you posted only 49 questions in the last 29 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes, and 59 seconds... Then waiting 1 second should let it go through.

Comment: Really, 30 questions in 30 days is probably plenty, though (but I assumed that was just a typo).

Comment: @jadarnel yeah, was on the way out the door & skimped on the proofing.